# how to do non blocking wait on a future for 10 seconds?

Tags: scala

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.util.Random

object Example1 extends App {
    println("starting calculation ...")
    val f = Future {
        sleep(Random.nextInt(500))
        42
    }
    println("before onComplete")
    f.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
        case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
    }

    sleep(2000)
}
```

Using Await.ready we can wait for 10 seconds and if the future is not completed it throws a TimeoutException. But Await.ready is blocking. What is the best way to wait for 10 seconds when using callback like in the above example ?(without using frameworks like Akka)

Comment: What do you mean **exactly** by "wait for 10 seconds" when you're using an asynchronous callback approach?  There isn't any obvious waiting going on, so it's not clear how a time limit would be applied or even make sense...  In other words, what are you trying to achieve that is different from an "infinite wait" asynchronous scenario?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to believe, but scala standard library does not include this functionality :( 
There are alternative `Future` implementations that do - like `com.twitter.util.Future` or `scalaz.concurrent.Future`, but with the standard scala `Future` you cannot get it out of the box.

You can implement it yourself, but that looks kinda ugly :(

```
  object FutureCancellator {
    val scheduler = ??? // You can use whatever scheduler available within your system - like akka scheduler or whatever, or roll your own, based on a timer thread.

     class Within[T](val f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def within(d: Duration): Future[T] = {
           val timeout: Future[T] = scheduler.after(d) { _ => 
              throw new TimeoutException(e)
           }
           Future.firstCompletedOf(f, timeout)
        }         
     }
  }
```

Now, you can do things like:

```
 import FutureCancellator._
 import scala.concurrent.duration._

 someFuture
   .within(10 seconds)
   .onComplete {
      case Success(foo) => println(s"got $foo")
      case Failure(t: TimeoutException) => println("timeout")
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
   }
```